# Tightvncserver on rapsberry pi not working - connection to mac

Tags: terminal, debian, raspberry-pi, vnc-server

today i installed a vncserver on my raspberry pi running rasbian. 
I used this tutorial: http://blog.wenzlaff.de/?p=2207 (its german but i think you will understand what they do there anyway ;) )
Everythin worked great but the tightvnc viever jar applet on my mac will not go further than "handshaking with remote host". After typing in my password of my pi, nothing is happening anymore.
I tried to look in the logs of tightvncserver on the pi , but i got a "permission denied" every time. 
Can you help me please. I dont know what do to now. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some problems with SSH-tunneling ( provided you were following the tutorial).

To diagnose what's happening, first it would be nice to figure out whether your `vncserver` is running on Raspberry. You can do it by issuing command:

`netstat -lnt`

The output can look something like below:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:587           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

We are interested to see if there's line:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

which basically tells us that our vncserver instance is listening on port 5901.

If that's true, then you should be able to use any VNC Viewer to connect to your RPI. Maybe you want to avoid SSH-tunnelling option and connect directly.